# Access Grunt config data within initConfig()

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

How can I access the Grunt config property `site` to read the `project.json` file at the path specified by the config property value?

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
  grunt.config('site', target);
  grunt.task.run('foo:dist', 'bar:dist');
});

grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  site: grunt.file.readJSON('./sites/' + grunt.config('site') + '/project.json')
});
```

**grunt-cli:**

```
grunt build:sitename

>> Error: Unable to read "./sites/undefined/project.json"
```

---

Using an [example](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#globals-and-configs) from the docs, I also tried this:

```
grunt.registerTask('global', 'site', function(prop, value) {
  global[prop] = val;
});

grunt.registerTask('build', ['foo:dist', 'bar:dist']);

grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  site: grunt.file.readJSON('./sites/' + global.site + '/project.json')
});
```

**grunt-cli:**

```
grunt global:site:sitename

>> Error: Unable to read "./sites/undefined/project.json"
```

---

**Update**:

Using the @FelixKling answer as a guide, I've made some progress:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
  grunt.config.set('target', target);
  grunt.config.set('site', grunt.file.readJSON('./sites/' + grunt.config.get('target') + '/project.json'));
  grunt.task.run('watch');
});

grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  site: grunt.config.get('site'),

  watch: {
    sass: {
      files: ['<%= site.dev %>/scss/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass:dist']
    }
  },

  sass: {
    dist: {
      files: {
        '<%= site.dist %>/style.css': '<%= site.dev %>/scss/style.scss'
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Now I'm able to read in the `project.json` file successfully, and (somehow) it's even able to recognize when edits are made to watched files. But for some reason when it runs the `sass:dist` task, I get this error: `Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (Cannot read property 'dev' of undefined).`

I'm not clear on how the `watch` task is able to get the correct value for `site`, but more importantly, I need to figure out a way to get that same value to the `sass` task.

Comment: Regarding your update, at the moment `grunt.file.readJSON('./sites/' + global.site + '/project.json')` runs, `global.site` doesn't exist yet since the `global` task didn't run yet. Check my answer again, I fixed  what was wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`initConfig` and `grunt.file.readJSON` run before your task runs. It seems like what you need are *template strings* and you can only call `grunt.file.readJSON` when you actually have the target name.

For example:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function(target) {
  grunt.config.set('target', target);
  grunt.config.set('site', grunt.file.readJSON(grunt.config.get('path'));
  grunt.task.run('foo:dist', 'bar:dist');
});

grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  path: './sites/<%= target %>/project.json'
});
```

More info: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config

---

Regarding your update: You are basically making the same mistake again as you did in your first example. You are trying to access the config `site` before it was set.

You have to understand that the initialization step, i.e. `grunt.initConfig` takes place **before** any task related code runs:

```
Initialize config -> Run task
```

Lets look at `grunt.initConfig` in isolation:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
  site: grunt.config.get('site'),
});
```

This is the initialization step, which happens before  everything else. The argument passed to `initConfig`, the configuration object, is evaluated first. What you are trying to do here is access the config options `site`, before the config was even created. I hope you recognize that this doesn't make sense.

Maybe it helps you to understand the process if you put `grunt.initConfig` at the very top, before you register any tasks.

---

**The solution:**

I think what you actually might be after are command-line arguments, with which you can control which site to build. See [`grunt.option`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) for more information.

For example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  watch: {
    sass: {
      files: ['<%= site.dev %>/scss/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['sass:dist']
    }
  }
});

grunt.config.set('site', grunt.file.readJSON('./sites/' + grunt.option('site') + '/project.json'));
```

And then you run the task with

```
grunt watch --site=somesite
```

Comment: Surely the inline grunt.file.readJSON() in initConfig will _still_ execute before registerTask.

Comment: @Rajit: Oops, forget to remove that part. Thanks!

Comment: When I run the code as shown, I get this error: `Unable to read "./sites/<% target %>/project.json"`. Is there a trick to getting Grunt to interpolate the variable when reading the file path?

Comment: I've updated my code to show progress made -- still not able to interpolate config variable within certain tasks. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: @cantera: Please see my update. `watch` works because you are setting the config properly before `watch` runs. All that `build` does is set config options and run task `watch`.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much for explaining in detail and walking me through the solution.

Comment: @cantera: Glad I could be of help :)

Comment: Should it be `<%= target %>` instead of `<% target %>`?

Comment: @naXa: yes! Fixed :)